# Como acessar o app por uma Url?

Tags: react-native, expo

Estou querendo acessar uma screen no meu projeto app, pelo celular, através de uma URL que foi mandada para o e-mail.

O projeto está sendo desenvolvido no expo e estou tentando usar o "linking" do expo mesmo, consultei a documentação do expo sobre linking (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/linking/), porem não consegui fazer com que tela exata abrisse.

No app.json está assim:

```
"expo":{
 "scheme": "myApp",
}
```

No route deixei assim:

```
TrocaSenha: {
 screen: TrocaSenha, 
 path: "trocaSenha/"
}
```

Estou tentando acessar através de uma URL assim

```
<a href="myApp://trocaSenha"> Acessar </a>
```

Porém quando acesso o link no celular ele abre a tela principal do projeto e não a tela de troca de senha.

Answer (score 0):

O que você necessita é de Deep Link, com ele você consegue configurar URLS para acessar o seu app. Existem configurações para Android e iOs que são feitas separadamente.

[Segue um exemplo de uma documentação em português](https://blog.rocketseat.com.br/configurando-deep-linking-no-react-native/)